# WPF DataBinding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I have a Grid inside another Grid, both Binded to a Model, the Parent Grid works well, but the child Grid Binding doesn't, I can't find the error, this is object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SAE_Connector
{
[XmlRoot("Configuracion")]
public class clsConfig
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Config config { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem]
    public List<PrePoliza> PrePolizas { get; set; }

    public clsConfig()
    {
        config = new Config();
        PrePolizas = new List<PrePoliza>();
    }
}

public class Config
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RutaDB { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        Impuestos = new clsImpuestos();
    }

    private string _numEmp = "";
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string NumEmp 
    { 
        get
        {
            return NumeroEmpresaGet();
        }
        set
        {
            _numEmp = NumEmp;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string InstanciaCompacSQL { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string EmpresaContPAQ { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string PassWord { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Impuestos")]
    public clsImpuestos Impuestos { get; set; }

    private string NumeroEmpresaGet()
    {
        string _result = "";
        string _emp = string.IsNullOrEmpty(RutaDB) == false ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RutaDB) : string.Empty;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_emp)==false)
        {
            //SAE50EMPRE02
            _result = _emp.Substring(_emp.Length - 2);
        }
        return _result;
    }
}

#region impuestos
    public class clsImpuestos
    {
    [XmlElement("Impuesto1")]    
    public clsImpuesto1 impuesto1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Impuesto2")]
    public clsImpuesto2 impuesto2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Impuesto3")]
    public clsImpuesto3 impuesto3 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Impuesto4")]
    public clsImpuesto4 impuesto4 { get; set; }

    public clsImpuestos()
    {
        impuesto1 = new clsImpuesto1();
        impuesto2 = new clsImpuesto2();
        impuesto3 = new clsImpuesto3();
        impuesto4 = new clsImpuesto4();
    }
    }

    public class clsImpuesto1
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public double Tasa { get; set; }
    }    
    public class clsImpuesto2
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public double Tasa { get; set; }
    }    
    public class clsImpuesto3
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public double Tasa { get; set; }
    }    
    public class clsImpuesto4
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public double Tasa { get; set; }
    }
#endregion

public enum eTipoPol { Ingresos, Egresos, Diario }

public class PrePoliza
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public eTipoPol tipoPol { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Concepto { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Cuenta> Cuentas { get; set; }

    public enum eCargoAbono { Cargo, Abono }
    public enum eProporcion { SubTotal, Impuesto1, Impuesto2, Impuesto3, Impuesto4, Total }
    public enum eReferenciaConcepto { Vacio, Observaciones, Folio, Texto }

    public PrePoliza()
    {
        Cuentas = new List<Cuenta>();
    }

    public class Cuenta
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string CuentaCod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool EsCuentaCte { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public eCargoAbono CargoAbono { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public eProporcion Proporcion { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public eReferenciaConcepto Referencia { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string RefText { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public eReferenciaConcepto Concepto { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ConcText { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

This is the complete XAML

```
<Window x:Class="wpfSaePolizas.xWindows.wPrePolizas"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Pre-Polizas" Height="600" Width="1000" Background="{StaticResource brBlue}" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource xTextBlockWhiteS}" >
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxRoundCorners}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brBorder}" Margin="5" >
        <Border.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel" >
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </Border.Resources>
        <ToolBar Margin="5" Background="Transparent">
            <Button Name="btnNva" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="90" Height="30" Click="btnNva_Click" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="..\img\Add1.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Nueva" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>

            <Button Name="btnEliminar" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="90" Height="30" Click="btnEliminar_Click" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="..\img\Del.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Eliminar" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>

            <Button Name="btnGuardar" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="90" Height="30" Click="btnGuardar_Click" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="..\img\Save.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Guardar" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>

            <Button Name="btnSalir" Background="{StaticResource gradGris}" Width="90" Height="30" Click="btnSalir_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Salir" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </Border>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Name="dgCuentas" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ></DataGrid>

        <Border Name="brConfig" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brBorder}" Margin="5" >
            <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
                <Grid Name="gridPrePoliza">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="Pre-Póliza:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ComboBox Name="cmbPrePolizas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="cmbPrePolizas_SelectionChanged" >
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <TextBlock Text="Nombre:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBox Name="txtNombre" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Nombre, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                    <TextBlock Text="Tipo de Póliza:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ComboBox Name="cmbTiposPoliza" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" >
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <TextBlock Text="Concepto Póliza:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBox Name="txtConceptoPol" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Concepto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                    <Grid Name="gridCuenta" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0, 20" IsEnabled="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                       <TextBlock Text="Cuenta:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBox Name="Cuenta" Width="157" Text="{Binding Path=CuentaCod, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="Cuenta_TextChanged"/>
                            <Button Name="btnCuentaBuscar" Content="..." Style="{StaticResource MetroButton}" Width="35" Click="btnCuentaBuscar_Click" Margin="0,0,0,3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblCuentaNombre" Text="{Binding Path=Descripcion, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <CheckBox Name="chbEsCteProv" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <CheckBox.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="Es Cuenta de Cliente/Proveedor" />
                            </CheckBox.Content>
                        </CheckBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="Cargo/Abono:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbCargoAbono" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="cmbCargoAbono_SelectionChanged" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="Proporción:" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbProporcion" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="cmbProporcion_SelectionChanged" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="Referencia:" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbRefer" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="cmbRefer_SelectionChanged" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <TextBox Name="txtRefer" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEnabled="False" 
                                 Text="{Binding Path=RefText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        <TextBlock Text="Concepto:" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbConcepto" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="cmbConcepto_SelectionChanged" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <TextBox Name="txtConcepto" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEnabled="False" 
                                 Text="{Binding Path=ConcText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    </Grid>

                    <Border Name="brCtasBotones" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brBorder}" 
                            Padding="5" CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel Name="stackBotones" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" >

                            <Button Name="btnNvaCta" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="80" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Click="btnNvaCta_Click" >
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="..\img\Nvo.png" Width="18" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Nueva" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button.Content>                                    
                            </Button>

                            <Button Name="btnEliminarCta" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="80" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Click="btnEliminarCta_Click" >
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="..\img\Del.png" Width="18" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Borrar" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Name="btnGuardarCta" Background="#FFFFD801" Width="80" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Click="btnGuardarCta_Click" >
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="..\img\Save.png" Width="18" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Guardar" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

This is for setting DataContext to Child Grid

```
PrePoliza.Cuenta _cta = new PrePoliza.Cuenta();
gridCuenta.DataContext = _cta;
```

And this is for setting DataContext to DataGrid

```
dgCuentas.ItemsSource = _prepoliza.Cuentas;
```

This is the Window of the UI:

http://postimg.org/image/ik94x4iwd/

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `DataContext` to an object.  The XML attributes are irrelevant at that point.  But, if you are trying to create a Cuenta and place it into the list of PrePoliza, then you should use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`, and you need to add the new _cta to the parent collection.

If you are binding to a DataGrid each row will bind to the implicit context of the row, so you just need to provide a simple binding directive.  For example:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
            <!--The Email property contains a URI.  For example "mailto:lucy0@adventure-works.com"-->
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"  ContentBinding="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource EmailConverter}}" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Member?" Binding="{Binding IsMember}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order Status"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

If you have gotten that far, but can't figure out how to get a TextBox into the DataGrid, then maybe use a [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/).

Comment: I Added XML Attributes because I serialize this object to XML for store ande retrieve data, I forgot to say the Parent is Binded to PrePoliza and this works well, the problem is with the Child Grid, the instance of Cuenta is added later to Prepolizas.Cuentas but my problem is how to bind controls to Cuenta, any example code??

Comment: Do you want the controls bound to the currently selected Cuentas?  Or a GrivView with controls bound to each Cuentas?

Comment: Maybe a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) bound to the PrePoliza.Cuentas collection?

Comment: I already have a DataGrid bound to Cuentas, I need the controls bound to an instance of Cuenta but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see a DataGrid anywhere in your example, so I am not sure what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I Updated de XAML code...
My Problem is not the DataGrid, is just I can't make work the Controls Binding to the instance of Cuenta

Comment: There is nothing in your DataGrid.  Please look at my updated answer for an example of the XAML to put inside of a DataGrid.  You should have DataGridTextColumn, DataGridTemplateColumn, etc.

Comment: Yes, there's no columns in the DataGrid, the Columns will be auto-generated

Comment: I post the wrong code for the Controls Binding, sorry, I don't need help for the DataGrid Binding, at least not for now, I just need the Controls to be Bound to an instance of Cuenta, I Update the Post and added a screenshot of the UI:  http://postimg.org/image/ik94x4iwd/